# JavaScript only works when pressing Ctrl + F5

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am trying to make a date-range-picker in my page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGAvv.png). And below is part of my code:

In daterangepicker.blade.php

```
<span id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
  <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</span>
```

In app.js

```
Vue.loadScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js")
    .then(() => {

        console.log('456');

        Vue.loadScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js")
        .then(() => {
            
            $(function() {

                console.log('789');
                var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
                var end = moment();
            
                function cb(start, end) {
                    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                }
            
                $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                    startDate: start,
                    endDate: end,
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    }
                }, cb);
            
                cb(start, end);
            
            });

            
        })
        .catch(() => {
        // Failed to fetch script
        });

        
    })
    .catch(() => {
    // Failed to fetch script
    });
```

The problem is the daterangepicker only works when I use Ctrl+F5 to refresh page. Once I refresh the page normally using only F5, it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUAG7.png).

In console, when I refresh the page normally, it loads very fast and console.log immediately but when I using hard-refresh, it takes quite a seconds to console.log the message I put in.

Comment: Looks like you could be mixing jQuery and vue [you should avoid doing this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: @Jon P the link you shared didn't discuss why you should not to mix jQuery and Vue but just to show how to mix if you want (?). So is this (mix jQuery and Vue) the real problem or there is other cause? appreciate your answer

Comment: Basically its the same with Vue , React, etc when it comes to jQuery, you have tow frameworks that use vewry differnt approaches to interacting with the DOM and often they don't play well together. You'd be better off using a vue component like https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker/ , https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-datepicker or something from https://morioh.com/p/e4968ba0aca0

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

When you do Control+F5, you are telling the browser to get all new files from the server. When you reload, only PHP files are really refreshed, unless the cache has expired.

When you refresh normally, it loads fast because your browser has already downloaded the files.

When you hard refresh, the files are re-downloaded from the server. Depending on the amount and their size, this can take a long time.

The date picker may not work when viewed on cache, because a recent change may have been made to the file that controls the datepicker.

Comment: Mind to elaborate your last sentence about `resent change may have been made to the file`? what file do you mean the `file`?